# Horizontal Locomotive scroll not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, animation, locomotive-scroll, locomotivejs

I'm using Locomotive scroll library to animate gallery view horizontaly on scroll.
Problem is mobile view.

See the demo:
[DEMO](https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/rNJaypJ?authentication_hash=mWAoNYxaLgXr)

```
 const lscroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
    smooth: true,
    direction: "horizontal"
  });
```

See the code: [CODE](https://codepen.io/Hastalavistababy/pen/rNJaypJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoint values (min width for the locomotive scroll to take effect) to 0.

```js
const lscroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
    smooth: true,
    direction: "horizontal",
    mobile: {
      breakpoint: 0,
      smooth: true,
      direction: "horizontal",
    },
    tablet: {
      breakpoint: 0,
      smooth: true,
      direction: "horizontal"
    },
});
```

Comment: just use `smartphone`  instead of `mobile` and you don't need to hack `breakpoint` then

Answer (score -1):

```
const lscroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
    smooth: true,
    direction: "horizontal",
    smartphone: {
      smooth: true,
      direction: "vertical" //use the direction according to your need//
    },
    tablet: {
      smooth: true,
      direction: "vertical" //use the direction according to your need//
    },
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).